# Django Search Implementation, conditional routing

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am trying to implement basic search functionality with Django. Could use help with accessing query inputs from forms in templates in functional or class based views. Intended functionality:

- If exact search query page exists, display that page
- If there is a page title that contains what was queried, show results of all
- If neither, display a message stating no results found

I'm just learning, so I tried functional views and class based views. I've spent a really long time on documentation/videos/textbooks and don't see how to get the intended behavior out of class-based view. I understand collecting object_list and getting query_set, but how do you then route to those three different conditions. I tried overriding dispatch() and as_views() method to no avail. Tried with a Django form class and without.

For some reason, the functional view keeps executing the first try statement instead of throwing a DoesNotExist exception when the exact match isn't found. So it shows the entry page instead of the search results page. It seems like the request.GET is None type no matter what, as when I try to print nothing shows up.

**urls.py**

```
from re import search
from django.urls import path

from . import views
from .views import IndexPageView, SearchView

app_name = "wiki"
urlpatterns = [
    # ex: /wiki/
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    # path("", IndexPageView.as_view(), name="index"),
    # ex: /wiki/EntryPageName
    path("wiki/<str:entry>/", views.displayEntry, name="displayEntry"),
    # path("wiki/search/", views.searchView, name="searchView")
    path("wiki/search/", SearchView.as_view(), name="searchView")
]
```

**model**

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title}"
    content = models.TextField()
```

**views.py**

```
def searchView(request):
    searchedTerm = request.GET.get('q')
    try:
        exactMatch = Entry.objects.get(title=searchedTerm)
        entryTitle = exactMatch.title
        entryHTML = markdown2.markdown(exactMatch.content)
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/displayEntry.html", {
            "entryTitle": entryTitle,
            "entryHTML": entryHTML
        })
    except:
        try:
            searchResults = Entry.objects.filter(Q(title__icontains=searchedTerm))
            return render(request, "encyclopedia/searchResults.html", {
                "searchResults": searchResults,
                "searchedTerm": searchedTerm
            })
        except:
            return render(request, "encyclopedia/searchResults.html", {
            "emptyResults": f"No entries found matching: {searchedTerm}",
            "searchedTerm": searchedTerm
        })

class SearchView(ListView):
    template_name = "encyclopedia/searchResults.html"
    model = Entry
    context_object_name = "searchList"

    def get_queryset(self):
        searchedTerm = self.request.GET.get('q')
        try:
            searchResults = Entry.objects.get(title=searchedTerm)
            return searchResults
        except:
            try:
                searchResults = Entry.objects.filter(Q(title__icontains=searchedTerm))
                return searchResults
            except:
                pass
            
    def as_view():
        searchedTerm = self.request.GET.get('q')
        try:
            exactMatch = Entry.objects.get(title=searchedTerm)
            entryTitle = exactMatch.title
            entryHTML = markdown2.markdown(exactMatch.content)
            return render(request, "encyclopedia/displayEntry.html", {
                "entryTitle": entryTitle,
                "entryHTML": entryHTML,
            })
        except:
            searchResults = Entry.objects.filter(Q(title__icontains=searchedTerm))
            return render(request, "encyclopedia/searchResults.html", {
                "searchResults": searchResults,
                "searchedTerm": searchedTerm
            })
        else:
            return render(request, "encyclopedia/searchResults.html", {
                "emptyResults": f"No entries found matching: {searchedTerm}",
                "searchedTerm": searchedTerm
            })
```

**search form from layout.html**

```
<form action="{% url 'wiki:search' %}" method="GET">
    <input class="search" type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search Encyclopedia">
    <!-- <input type="submit" value="submit"> -->
</form>
```

display entry page template

```
{% extends "encyclopedia/layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    {% if entryTitle %}
        {{ entryTitle }}
    {% else %}
        Page Not Found!
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    {% if entryHTML %}
        {{ entryHTML|safe }}
    {% else %}
        <p>This page does not exist yet.</p>
        <p>Check your spelling or create a new entry!</p>
        <p>?? {{ testPrint }}</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

search results page

```
{% extends "encyclopedia/layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Search Results: {{ searchedTerm }}
{% endblock %}


{% block body %}

    {% if searchResults %}
        <h3>Search Results</h3>
        <ul>
            {% for result in searchResults %}    
                <li><a href="{% url 'wiki:displayPage' result.title %}">{{ result.title }}</a></li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% else %}
        <h3>{{ emptyResults }}</h3>        
    {% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Models

```
class Entry(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
   content = models.TextField()

   def __str__(self):
     return self.title
```

Views

```
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
from app.models import Entry

class EntryListView(ListView):

   model = Entry
   paginate_by = 100  # if pagination is desired

   def get_queryset(self):
     queryset = super().get_queryset()
     q = self.request.GET.get("q")
     if q:
        queryset = queryset.filter(title__icontains=q)
     return queryset


 class EntryDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Entry
```

Urls

```
from django.urls import path

from app.views import EntryListView, EntryDetailView

urlpatterns = [
    path('', EntryListView.as_view(), name='entry-list'),
    path('<int:pk>/', ArticleDetailView.as_view(), name='entry-detail'),
]
```

Comment: Can you explain what's going on with the get_queryset override? Also, how does this know how to go directly to an entry's page or the search results page

Comment: the search form is in the list view template , then you have a sepparate url for each entity

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't fully understanding class-based views. For anyone wondering, this vod was most helpful in explaining it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F5mRW0jo-U4&t=8720s